# Joomla show user registration form inside article

Tags: joomla-3.x

I need to add a user registration form inside an article. I know I can insert a login form using:

```
{loadmodule mod_login}
```

but is there any way to load only the registration form?

Comment: Use the plugin load module in an article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extensions for achieving this functionality.

Here's link to the extension I'm aware of that allow you to put a registration form in a module:

[S5 Register](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/s5-register) (Free)

The `S5 Register module` is simply is a module that allows for user registration on any page via a module, its an exact copy of the default Joomla page but can be published to a `module position`.

[RSform!Pro](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/plugins-and-modules/rsformpro-joomla-user-registration-plugin.html) (Paid)

Now using `loadmodule` or `loadpostilion` you can put registration form anywhere in your site.